# Binary rating system with PHP and SQL without logging in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I am working on a simple Content Management System featuring posts that can be rated up or down, with a score and appearance similar to Reddit's system.

The rating arrows trigger a javascript function like this:

```
rateQuote(postID, value, this);
```

PostID being the identifier of the referenced post, value being 1 for Up / 0 for Down and 'this' for jQuery DOM access.

`rateQuote()` looks like this:

```
function rateQuote(quoteId, rateValue, triggerElement) {

    if (localStorage.getItem(quoteId)) { return false; };

    var scoreContainer = $(triggerElement).closest('.qcntscore').children('.qcntscore-span');
    var scoreNumber = Number(scoreContainer.text());

    if (rateValue == 1) { scoreNumber++; }
    else if (rateValue == 0) { scoreNumber--; };

    scoreContainer.text(scoreNumber);

    localStorage.setItem(quoteId, rateValue);

    $(triggerElement).addClass('rating-active');
    $.ajax({
        url: "../rate.php",
        data: {quote: quoteId, ratevalue: rateValue},
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) { if(data) {console.log(data);} }
    });
}
```

So this is doing three things:

- Write to and read from HTML5 `localStorage` to block multiple votes
- Target the element (there can be multiple on one page), change the visuals and the score number respectively
- Trigger an AJAX request to `rate.php`, transmitting `postID`and the value of the vote to it via POST.

`rate.php` looks like this:

```
<?php 

include_once('parts/includer.php');

if(isset($_POST['quote'], $_POST['ratevalue'])) {

    $post = (int)$_POST['quote'];
    $rating = (int)$_POST['ratevalue'];

    if(in_array($rating, array(1, 0))) { //Is Rating valid? (0 or 1)
        if($rating == 0) {
            $rating = -1;
        }
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $post);
        $query->execute();
        //Does the post exist?

        if($query->rowCount() > 0) { //It does.

            echo 'Post Exists - ';

            //Check if Post is already mentioned.
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM post_ratings WHERE post_id = ?");
            $query->bindValue(1, $post);
            $query->execute();

            if($query->rowCount() > 0) { //It is.
                echo 'Rating Exists, Updating.';
                $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE post_ratings SET score = score + ? WHERE post_id = ?");
                $query->bindValue(1, $rating);
                $query->bindValue(2, $post);
                $query->execute();

            } else {
                echo 'Rating Created';
                $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO post_ratings (post_id, score) VALUES (?, ?)");
                $query->bindValue(1, $post);
                $query->bindValue(2, $rating);
                $query->execute();
            }

        }
    }
}

?>
```

This is just doing a bit of validation and then submits or changes the info in the SQL database.

So now on to my question: How can i ensure that one user can only rate each post once? I explicitly don't want them to register, and there are other major sites that employ some solution that works like this (For instance, Squarespace has a 'Love' button that requires no login / registration in order to be clicked by the user).

My `localStorage` solution is of course not remotely safe and just client-sided (reset your localStorage or just make the AJAX call via a console), but i implemented it to take some load from the server, since 95% of the user base won't exploit the rating.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use `IP Address` as a unique identifier...

Comment: Is that actually a good practice? Multiple users in one house or even one office would overlap, wouldn't they?

Comment: No, it isn't good practice. If anything, you'd want to use the person's ID rather than an IP address. @JonJomate

Comment: @Fred-ii- What exactly are you referring to? Person's ID as in some unique number like a MAC address?

Comment: No, as in and if your DB contains a column called `ID` for instance and setting that as a PK or UNIQUE with AUTO_INCREMENT kind of thing.